# Installing pandas library in python is too slow. How can i get over this?

Tags: python, pandas, installation, import

I want to make a question:
I want to install pandas in python jupyter notebook to import data from my desktop.This command is very slow and write for over an hour.
Collecting pandas
Using cached pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... /
How can i get over this?

I tried to install via command prompt but i didnt get over this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the latest version of pip installed. You can upgrade pip with the below command

```
'pip install --upgrade pip'
```